# Reshaping data from a grid and populating a column with the data frame name

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, csv, tidyr

Main question: Is there a way to populate a df with the data frame name other than just typing it in and pasting it manually?

I have 20 csv files in a folder that have a grid of data that looks somewhat like this.
File 1:

|  | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Y2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Y3 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

File 2:

|  | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y1 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| Y2 | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| Y3 | 3 | 6 | 9 |

Note: X1,2,3 and Y1,2,3 are co-ordinates, while the populated values are just example values and are not indicative of any pattern

Each file has a unique ID e.g., US_plot_1.csv, US_plot_2.csv, UK_plot_1.csv, US_plot_2.csv,

I want to populate a df that sorts these files into columns that R can analyse, grouped by filename i.e.,

| filename | X | Y | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US_plot_1 | X1 | Y1 | 1 |
| US_plot_1 | X1 | Y2 | 4 |
| US_plot_1 | X1 | Y3 | 7 |
| US_plot_1 | X2 | Y1 | 2 |
| US_plot_1 | X2 | Y2 | 5 |
| US_plot_1 | X2 | Y3 | 8 |
| US_plot_1 | X3 | Y1 | 3 |
| US_plot_1 | X3 | Y2 | 6 |
| US_plot_1 | X3 | Y3 | 9 |
| US_plot_2 | X1 | Y1 | 1 |
| US_plot_2 | X1 | Y2 | 2 |
| US_plot_2 | X1 | Y3 | 3 |

I understand for the populating the data I can loop it.

```
df<- lapply(Sys.glob("*.csv"), read.csv) #to load all the csvs
df<- as.data.frame(df)
df<-lapply(split(sequence(ncol(df)), rep(1:(4/4), each = 4)), function(x) df[, x])

filenames<- list.files(path=getwd())  #to get the filenames
filenames2<- substr(filenames, 1, 9)

for (i in 1:20) {
     assign(paste(filenames2[i], i), data.frame(df[[i]]))
}
```

Then when I need to change each data into an r-analysable df I can use the *tidyr* package with gather():

```
US_plot_1<-DF %>% gather (X_coord, Value, X1:X3)
```

I know I can always resort to just manually pasting it in using

```
US_plot_1$filename<-paste("US_plot_1")
```

But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this within the `lapply` command :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

filenames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")

df<- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  #Read the csv
  read.csv(x) %>%
    #Get the data in long format, gather is retired using pivot_longer
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('X')) %>%
    #Adding a new column as filename
    mutate(filename = tools::file_path_sans_ext(x))
})
```

If you want them as separate dataframes :

```
names(df) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(filenames)
list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I realise I never replied: thank you very much!